# Redirect only if a URL query matches

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

How to config apple-app-site-association to open/redirect only link with specific url query?
For example I would like to open only links like this https://www.example.com/?modal=CreatePassword

This is my current config an it opens all links even without the url query (modal=CreatePassword)

```
"applinks": {
        "details": [
            {
                "appIDs": [
                    "com.app"
                ],
                "components": [
                    {
                        "?": {
                            "modal": "CreatePassword"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that iOS keeps/downloads old file even after reinstallation of the app(delete -> install). This video was very helpful: https://youtu.be/xxyEq_ySoO4

I downloaded `sysdiagnose` file from my iPhone and checked `swcutil_show.txt`, and found that it keeps old version of the  apple-app-site-association file.

The correct config for me:

```
{
  "applinks": {
      "details": [
           {
             "appIDs": [ "com.app" ],
             "components": [{
                "?":{"modal":"CreatePassword"},
                "/":"/"
              }
             ]
           }
       ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OP did you have to add path `"/"` to make query param work or after 24hrs it just worked?

```
{
  "applinks": {
      "details": [
           {
             "appIDs": [ "com.app" ],
             "components": [{
                "?":{"modal":"CreatePassword"},
                "/":"/"
              }
             ]
           }
       ]
   }
}
```

Comment: It indeed worked just adding the query param selector 24hrs after change applied. Magic!